# How to add storyboard canvas orientation in git ignore in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, git, gitignore

I know this seems really obvious question but I have gone through a lot of different git ignore files but still I am unable to control this one file.
**What is the issue?**
[image]

[image]

**How it occurred?** 
I just changed the one view controller's position in the storyboard.

**What I need?**
Any possible way to add this file into git ignore so that I can avoid these simple merge conflicts? Also, I cannot add this storyboard into git ignore because I want to reflect the changes in View Controllers which I actually made. On my previous macbook, it was working fine, no idea why the same git ignore is not working anymore?

Comment: There is no problem and you have nothing to ignore. You made a change, now you need to commit it. No problem. There is no conflict. There is no merge. Just stage the hunk and commit. Done.

Comment: @matt in iOS you don't want to make commits based on simple storyboard changes. These changes are tracked in a file .xcuserstate and it should be in git ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's showing "Changes not staged for commit" rather than something about untracked files, what this means is that you have `Main.storyboard` *already being tracked by Git*. In other words, as soon as you add a file to Git and commit it, that file becomes tracked, meaning that Git will be monitoring it for changes.

`.gitignore` does *not* work for tracked files, but rather only untracked files. You can use

```
git rm --cached Nava/UI/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
```

to remove it from the index, and then commit that. Now, if you have the `.gitignore` file properly set up to ignore that file, you won't see it coming up anymore.